# How to determine UFC of an address book program

Tags: software-quality, function-points

I am trying to find the Unadjusted function count(UFC) for an address book program. According to the research I conducted on the internet, I found out that I need to measure the following:

1. External inputs.
2. External outputs.
3. External inquiries.
4. External files.
5. Internal files.

My question is, how to find the above measures of the address book program.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably download an example address book program and try and link the EI's, ET's etc from the spelling checker program with those that you can identify from the spelling checker slides in lecture 4.

Ps... Stefans watching you...

Comment: What? you should make this a general answer so everyone can understand